# Retornar dos una variable en dos vistas

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una vista que se llama show, a la cual quiero ponerle un select, definidos en la variable $usuariosOpciones, el problema es que esta variable solo retorna a usuario.index, hay alguna manera de que tambien la pueda retornar a usuario.show?

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $usuarios=usuarios::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
        $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
        return view('usuario.index',compact('usuarios','usuariosOpciones')); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un nuevo método:

```
public function usuariosOpciones(){
    return usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
}
```

Luego simplemente llamas al método `usuariosOpciones()`

```
public function index(){
  $usuariosOpciones = $this->usuariosOpciones();
}
```

Y en tu método `show` harías lo mismo:

```
public function show($id){
  $usuariosOpciones = $this->usuariosOpciones();
}
```

Comment: Gracias marcial, lo pude arreglar

Comment: Que bueno, recuerda que puedes cerrar tu pregunta dando clic en el ícono check. Saludos.